# Retrieve text from edittext within tab to main activity

Tags: kotlin, android-tabbed-activity

I have an activity with a tabbed layout containing multiple different tabs. Each tab contains a number of 'edittext' fields. I have a button on the main activity and on clicking it i want to save the the contents of each edittext field from each tab. Currently i can return an ordinary value from the tab but i can not get the contents of the edittext field.

I have tried creating a 'lateinit var frag1_tenNo : EditText' within the fragment class for a tab. I have initialized it in the onCreateView but the program crashes saying 'lateinit property frag1_tenNo has not been initialized'

fragment code

```
class frag1: Fragment() {

   lateinit var frag1_tenNo : EditText

    override public fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val viewFrag1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag1, container, false)
        frag1_tenNo = viewFrag1.findViewById(R.id.survey_tenantNo)
        return viewFrag1
    }

    fun saveFrag1Data(): String {
        var data1 = frag1_tenNo.text.toString()
        return data1
    }
```

activity code - to retrieve data

```
save_btn.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("Survey","Change Button Clicked")
            val test = frag1().saveFrag1Data()
            Log.d("Survey","Returned value : $test")
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`val test = frag1().saveFrag1Data()`
Here you create a new fragment. `OnCreate` method of this fragment isn't called yet. So quite predictably you get `lateinit property frag1_tenNo has not been initialized` error.

Comment: thank you, that makes sense now. how would i access the edittext field within the tab from my main activity to retrieve any text i've entered?

Comment: @ConorSproule It depends on your implementation. You need get access to instances of fragments you previously created.

Comment: ok Andrew, this may now be beyond me, i'm only new to programming and struggling with the terms. i don't suppose you have a link to an answer that could direct me to dealing with this issue/accessing instances of fragments that have been created?

Comment: i have sorted this now, i couldn't get findViewById to work because i was creating a new fragment each time. i now use it with the container the fragment was inflated in. works fine.